# Laravel join query using Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

i have two tables 'users' and 'projects'

Table users

```
-----------------------------------
user_id | name | email | password |
-----------------------------------
   1    |name1 |email1 | password1|
-----------------------------------
   2    |name2 |email2 | password2|
```

Table projects

```
 project_id  |user_id | name          | 
 --------------------------------------
    1        |   1    | project_name1 |
 -----------------------------------
    2        |   1    | project_name2 |
```

There is no relation between these two tables but user_id in projects are the id from user table.

Normal Query

SELECT a.user_id,a.name AS username,b.name AS project_name FROM users a LEFT JOIN projects b ON a.user_id=b.user_id;

I want the same query execution in laravel eloquent.

Have searched in google got some idea about "with" function but not able to get the output.

Thanks.

Comment: it is not clear what your question is. please state what result you expect.

Comment: Are you using `DB::raw` ?

Comment: @1010 i need to join two tables the normal query i have mentioned. The same output i have to accomplish in laravel eloquent. for eg : using User::all() like statements.

Comment: if you want it with eloquent you should have primary and foreign keys defined in the tables in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way you should use Eloquent:
create User.php

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Project');
    }

}
```

create Project.php

```
<?php

class Project extends Eloquent
{
}
```

On controller, write this to get all users, with related projects inserted inside each users:

```
$users = User::with('projects')->all();
foreach($users as $user)
{
    $project_of_this_user = $user->projects;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this will help for relations but if i have no relation between users and projects how can i put where condition.

Comment: `$users = User::with('projects')->where('email', '=', 'example@example.com')->get();` OR
`$users = User::where('email', '=', 'example@example.com')->get();`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do as following,

```
DB::table('users')
        ->join('projects =', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
        ->select('*')
        ->get();
```

For more details you can refer [laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins)

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you need:

```
DB::table('users')
  ->join('projects', 'projects.user_id', '=', 'users.user_id')
  ->select('users.user_id', 'users.name as username', 'projects.name as project_name')
  ->get();
```

Comment: I have tried these and are working. I need to do it using laravel model. I have created User model class for 'users' and Project class for 'projects'

Answer (score 1):

I think, this one helps you out

```
    DB::table('users')
            ->leftJoin('projects', 'users.user_id', '=', 'projects.user_id')
            ->select('users.user_id', 'users.name as username', 'projects.name as project_name')
            ->get();
```